# Как отловить в Питоне inf, -inf, nan

Tags: python, nan

Я чайник, не понимаю совсем как это сделать. Нужно чтобы код возвращался к стадии записи переменных в случае если `D == inf -inf nan`, а если он не равен им, то продолжал работу по нахождению иксов. Код также отлавливает ошибки и возвращает к заполнению переменных если ввести строковое или символьное значения.

```
import math


while True:
    print("Введите коэффициенты для уравнения - целые или рациональные числа (не бесконечно большие или малые)")
    print("ax^1+bx+c=0")
    try:
        a = float(input("a="))
        b = float(input("b="))
        c = float(input("c="))
    except ValueError:
        print("Это не целое или рациональное число")
        continue
    D = b ** 2-4 * a * c
    print("Дискриминант D = %.2f" % D)

    # if D == float("inf") or float("-inf") or ("nan"):
    #     print("Габелла, переполнение")
    #     continue

    if D > 0:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        print("x1 = %.2f \nx2 = %.2f" % (x1, x2))
    elif D == 0:
        x = -b / (2 * a)
        print("x = %.2f" % x)
    else:
        print("Корней нет")
    break
```

Comment: `if D in [float("inf"), float("-inf"), float("nan")]:`

Comment: спасибо! Но nan всё равно не ловит, пишет D = nan корней нет. И еще не понятно как вернуть его на ввод переменных заново

Comment: Так `continue` в этом `if` и должно вернуть к вводу переменных. А про `nan` я прогнал, надо проверять `math.isnan(D)`, т.е. `if D in [float("inf"), float("-inf")] or math.isnan(D):` Вернее, лучше и `inf` так же проверять через `math.isinf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе вашего кода, `continue` должен вернуть цикл к моменту ввода переменных. А на `inf` и `nan` лучше проверять с помощью специальных функций пакета `math`. Причём функция `isinf` выдаёт `True` и на `inf` и на `-inf`:

```py
if math.isinf(D) or math.isnan(D):
    print("Габелла, переполнение")
    continue
```

Как правильно подсказывают в комментарии, проверка `if not math.isfinite(D):` покрывает сразу все эти варианты.

Comment: [isfinite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isfinite)

Comment: @user207200 Кстати да, хороший вариант

Comment: Благодарю! Всё робит)). Остался последний вопрос - нашел ошибку еще одну, когда вводишь больше обычного значения, но меньше бесконечности, в уравнении D выдает OverflowError, try exept не может это поймать. Не знаете как отловить её тоже?

Comment: Так чтобы это поймать нужно само вычисление `D` тоже обернуть в отдельный `try except`. Только внутри такого блока ошибки ловятся.

Comment: да, до этого догадался, но он энивей не ловит именно эту

Comment: А какую ошибку там в `except` ловите? Попробуйте в `except` указывать именно `OverflowError`, либо просто `Error`, либо вообще `BaseError`. Если и так не поймает, значит сам интерпретатор грохается. `except ValueError:` не поймает `OverflowError`, конечно.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо больше еще раз)